# Validar entrada de numero negativo java

Tags: java, validación, while

necesito mostrar por pantalla un mensaje de error cuando se intente ingresar un valor menor a 0, el programa funciona con un while pero no me interesa que muestre el mismo mensaje de entrada de datos, sino un mensaje que se ha introducido un valor incorrecto y que vuelva a mostrar el menú, alguna sugerencia? gracias

```
public class Ejercicio04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

       int opcion;
            do{
                System.out.println("Introduzca la operacion a realizar del siguiente menu de opciones:");
                System.out.println("1 Añadir refresco del primer recipiente.");
                System.out.println("2 Traspasar refresco del primer al segundo recipiente.");
                System.out.println("3 Quitar refresco del segundo recipiente.");
                System.out.println("0 Finalizar");

                opcion = read.nextInt();

                float recipienteUno = 0, recipienteDos = 0, numero;

                switch(opcion){

                case 1:
                 do{
                          System.out.print("Ingrese valor en decimales: ");
                          recipienteUno=read.nextFloat();

                   }while(recipienteUno < 0);

                        System.out.println("El primer recipiente contiene " + recipienteUno);
                        System.out.println("El segundo recipiente contiene " + recipienteDos);
                        break;
```

Comment: No comprendo bien tu pregunta. En que parte es donde me tiene que generar el error que comentas.

Comment: Necesitamos ver el código completo, para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tú código no está bien escrito te falta las llaves de cierre de la clase, al igual que las llaves del switch, por otra parte imagino que tienes que elegir unas de las opciones que pones, así que intenta con el `default`mandar un mensaje cuando el número es negativo...

Comment: Lamento la falta de claridad en la pregunta, intentare mejorar, lo pude solventar de todas formas, muchas gracias